# Production build infinite loading error next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, build

I am using [Next.js TypeScript starter](https://github.com/jpedroschmitz/typescript-nextjs-starter) for my project. After creating some components and files my project I just want to make a build when I try to make a build it is showing infinite loading. My project is working fine without any error

Things I already tried to solve this issue

1. Check if any file is empty
2. Remove node_modules and .next folder and start build command again
3. Double check if my code have any error

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: What should I provide there is a whole project

Answer (score 1):

This error is because of having empty file in public folder .